# Please help me understand this nios2 code

Tags: assembly, nios

We're supplied some [assembly](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1500/2012/nios2int/nios2int1main.s) for nios2 that I don't fully understand. If we can start with this instruction then I don't understand what it's for:

`.set noat           # required since we push r1`

What does it mean? I looked in the manual but there was nothing that matched this.

Besides the instruction above I think that I can understand the individual instructions but I still can't really get a good grip what the program is for. We used it with our C code to do laboratory exercises for a computer engineering course and now I sort of forget what the code does and I wonder if you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7912203/278976), it disables/enables warning when $at register is used by the user.

```
.set noat           # required since we push r1
.macro PUSHMOST
    PUSH  at        # push assembler-temporary register r1
    PUSH  r2
    PUSH  r3
    PUSH  r4
```

See the comment to the right of PUSH at

And according to [this document](http://refcards.com/docs/waetzigj/mips/mipsref.pdf), it:

> prevents SPIM from complaining if subsequent instructions use $at